# My Drupal Website is Working at Desktop , but for mobile it displaying 'site can't reached'

Tags: drupal, server, drupal-7

My Drupal Website is Working at Desktop , but for mobile it displaying 'site can't reached'

I have created a custom form . Where I store data as variable.

```
function meme_common_settings() {

$form['azure_login'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Azure Login status'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('azure_login', 0),
    '#description' => t('To enable Azure Login.'),
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

When I checked check box and enable  azure_login functionality. It is working fine at my desktop but not working at mobile browser. In Mobile browser it is displaying

> 'site can't reached'

.

But When I unchecked azure_login functionality, My website is working fine for mobile browser also. I can't understand what issue here...

After enabled azure_login , I put echo & die at index.php. It is working fine for Desktop , but not working at mobile browser. Still displaying "site can't reached"...

Answer (score 0):

Add that lines at the top of index.php to see all php errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

See drupal errors log http://my_site.com  /admin/reports/dblog

See httpd server (apache, nginx) error log.

May be mobile browser is too old (some time old browsers not display site throught https, problems with ssl).

Comment: It not hit index.php... 

If it hit index.php , then I can debug.. but I echo some thing at index.php , that not coming ...

Comment: I also checked  apache error log.. nothing is there